# Displaying Real Time Date

Tags: php

i'm trying to display today real date on inputbox
but the problem is when user date settings is incorrect
the data that will display in inputbox will be incorrect
Is it possible to display the real exact date to inputbox

here is  my commmand

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
 echo "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Date: </span>". date('F j, Y g:i:a  ');
```

Comment: Are you trying to override the browsers default timezone? It would typically be best to leave this to the browser, unless there is a reason to override it?

Comment: Right now my computer date is incorrect so when i used those command the date that is displaying in inputbox is incorrect. Is there like a way to display the correct date to my input box?

Comment: Whose real date do you want, the client or the server? Your code will use the date as it is set on the server running your PHP code, won't it?

Comment: I don't get this question... Are you asking how to get the correct time from a wrong clock? Isn't that like asking how to get the right temperature if your thermometer is broken?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if the date/time on the machine running PHP is incorrect you will get incorrect results, I suggest connecting this PC to a time server to obtain the correct date/time using NTP,

Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings

Linux: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-time-from-linux-command-prompt/